# Problem with CLI installing module

Tags: magento2, module, composer, cli

[image: Got this message in CLI]

Im trying to install sitemap module for Magento 2 and i got this message via cli, i make some changes in composer.json

```
   {
"name": "mageplaza/module-sitemap",
  "minimum-stability":"dev"
  "description": "Magento 2 Google XML Sitemap extension",
  "require": {
    "mageplaza/module-core": "^1.3.11",
    "mageplaza/magento-2-seo-extension": "^2.1.0"
    "mageplaza/module-sitemap": "@dev"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Mageplaza",
      "email": "support@mageplaza.com",
      "homepage": "https://www.mageplaza.com",
      "role": "Technical Support"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Mageplaza\\Sitemap\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

but i cant install it ... any suggest?

Comment: actually u have to execute the composer from magento 2 from root right? have u tried like that?

Comment: how actually i do this?

Comment: Using command like go to Magento root folder and execute u r composer command for mageplaza

Comment: not working. ...